# How to change background image of all activities at runtime android

Tags: android

I am getting background image from server and I want to set that image as a background for all the activities in my app.

Comment: Cool, good to know. What have you tried? Have a go first, we don't write code for you!

Comment: Please findViewByID your "PARENT_CONTAINER" of your xml in Java, & "PARENT_CONTAINER.SETBACKGROUND("your_image_goes_here")".

I am assuming, you know how to handle the Images from Server to set in the Parent_container.

Comment: If you want more help. Please paste one of your xml's & your JAVA code.